# I m installing OROCRM have issue with the requirement

Tags: php

Hello everyone am really in need of help,

Am tasks to install and configure orocrm on untubu 14.0 is been two days in having issue with "memory_limit should be at least 512M Set the "memory_limit" setting in php.ini* to at least "512M" even i set the 512M on the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini its still given me the same error. could anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing OroCRM through console please change memory_limit in "/etc/php5/cli/php.ini".

If you are installing it through web browser, please restart apache after changing php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my issue was solved on the virtual host adding the value_php limit to 152MB.